# r - matching of two dataframes and insertion of rows from one in another on condition

Tags: r, dataframe, insert, rows

Recently I have been trying to produce a certain output using 2 dataframes but it seems my R experience is still not sufficient to do this. I have spent many hours but am not able to find an answer how to do this. Any help on the following task is appreciated.

I have two datasets `base_df` and `compare_df`. Specific elements (cells) from `compare_df` need to be inserted in `base_df` using the following rules:

a) element from `id` column from `base_df` and element from `id` from `compare_df` should be equal

b) if number from xx, yy or zz, after the character is separated using separator `_` for ex. "1.5_2.5" could be saved in 2 separate variables like `val1` = 1.5 and `val2` = 2.5 , so:
if `(compare_df$val1 > base_df$var1 & compare_df$val1 < lead(base_df$var1)) & (compare_df$val2 > base_df$var2 & compare_df$val2 < lead(base_df$var2))` then insert values `val1` and `val2` from `compare_df` between rows 1 and 2 in `base_df`.

c) use the name of the variable for which the exchange was done, in this case for ex. create new variable let's say `ind`, and assign value to this variable for newly created row2 in `base_df` equal to "xx".

Note: `compare_df` has many columns like `xx,yy and zz` for which the process needs to be done as well. So the condition is checked for all columns in `compare_df` except for id.

**Basically every row information from `compare_df` should be compared to all rows in `base_df` and see if the conditions are fulfilled. There might be multiple matches. The original order of the rows should be kept so `arrange` cannot be used since `var1` and `var2` are not increasing with the number of row. Maybe it can be done with the `apply` functions ?**

Below are simplified examples:

```
base_df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"), 
                      var1 = c(1,3,5,-7,-9,11,13,15,17,19),
                      var2 = c(2,4,6,8,-10,12,14,16,18,20))

compare_df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b"), 
                     xx = c("1.5_2.5", "17.5_18.5"),
                     yy = c("3.5_2.5", "12.5_18.5"),
                     zz = c("3.5_4.5", "15.5_16.5"))

# desired
final_df <- data.frame(
  id = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"),
  ind = c("org", "xx", "org", "zz", "org", "org", "org", "org", "org", "org", "zz", "org", "xx", "org"),
  var1 = c(1, 1.5, 3, 3.5, 5, -7, -9, 11, 13, 15, 15.5, 17, 17.5, 19),
  var2 = c(2, 2.5, 4, 4.5, 6, 8, -10, 12, 14, 16, 16.5, 18, 18.5, 20))
```

[image: Simplified example result below]

Comment: What do `old` and `org` in your desired output mean?

Comment: the value of the  `ind` column in the `final_df` should indicate where did the `var1` and `var2` values come from. When it is "org" this means they come from `base_df`, if it is "xx", "yy" or "zz" then it means these values were inserted in `base_df` from `compare_df`. The "old" value should have been "org", it was a mistake. I fixed it

Comment: I have also updated my post based on your updated information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse). Assuming that rows from the original `base_df` is called `old` in the `ind` column in the new data frame. It is not entirely clear what are your filtering conditions, but I tried to match your expected output. `new_df` is the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)

compare_df2 <- compare_df %>%
  gather(ind, value, -id) %>%
  separate(value, into = c("var1", "var2"), sep = "_", convert = TRUE)

new_df <- base_df %>%
  mutate(ind = "org") %>%
  bind_rows(compare_df2) %>%
  select(id, ind, var1, var2) %>%
  arrange(id, var1, var2) %>%
  filter(var2 > var1) %>%
  filter(row_number() != which(var2 < lag(var2)) - 1)

new_df
#    id ind var1 var2
# 1   a org  1.0  2.0
# 2   a  xx  1.5  2.5
# 3   a org  3.0  4.0
# 4   a  zz  3.5  4.5
# 5   a org  5.0  6.0
# 6   a org  7.0  8.0
# 7   a org  9.0 10.0
# 8   b org 11.0 12.0
# 9   b org 13.0 14.0
# 10  b org 15.0 16.0
# 11  b  zz 15.5 16.5
# 12  b org 17.0 18.0
# 13  b  xx 17.5 18.5
# 14  b org 19.0 20.0
```

Comment: I checked and the `arrange` function shouldn't be used since `var1` and `var2` from `base_df` are not always increasing. They might decrease and then by arranging after binding the original order will be lost. I updated the `base_df` dateset to include this important info.

Comment: @adl If it is not ordered by `var1` and `var2`, and then I have no idea what the order should be. Perhaps you can keep this question open and wait to see if others can solve this.

Comment: maybe it can be done with `apply` by comparing all rows in `compare_df` with all rows in `base_df`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible tidy verse solution:

```
base_df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"), 
                      var1 = seq(1,20, by = 2),
                      var2 = seq(2,21, by = 2))

compare_df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b"), 
                         xx = c("1.5_2.5", "17.5_18.5"),
                         yy = c("3.5_2.5", "12.5_18.5"),
                         zz = c("3.5_4.5", "15.5_16.5"))


# Reshape compare_df to long
compare_df <- gather(compare_df, ind, value, -id)
# Sep the compare_df by "_"
compare_df <- separate(compare_df, col=value, into = c("var1", "var2"), sep = "_")

# Add the "org" column to base_df
base_df$ind <- "org"
# Combine and sort the dfs
final_df2 <- rbind(base_df, compare_df) %>%
  arrange(id, var1)

# I think you wanted to only keep compare_df where var1 was < var2?
final_df2 <- filter(final_df2, var1 < var2)
final_df2

   id var1 var2 ind
1   a    1    2 org
2   a  1.5  2.5  xx
3   a    3    4 org
4   a  3.5  4.5  zz
5   a    5    6 org
6   a    7    8 org
7   b   11   12 org
8   b 12.5 18.5  yy
9   b   13   14 org
10  b   15   16 org
11  b 15.5 16.5  zz
12  b   17   18 org
13  b 17.5 18.5  xx
14  b   19   20 org
```